# How to get ONLY unblocked author email of git commit

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to send an email notification from jenkins to the authors of a git commit.

To get git commit authors, I used a sh script:

```
git_emails = sh ( 
          script: "git log --format='%cE%n%aE%n%gE' ${gitLogCommand} | sort -u", 
          returnStdout: true 
        ).trim()
```

Before sending an email, I need to check if the returned authors are blocked or not in Gitlab.

is any one have an idea how to do that ! Thank you.

Edit: Block user from Gitlab

[image]

Comment: What do you mean, blocked authors? AFAIK, git has no concept of blocking. Are you mixing up git and GitHub? You can check whether you've blocked a user using GitHub's [`GET /user/blocks/:username` API v3 endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/blocking/#check-whether-youve-blocked-a-user).

Comment: In gitLab, I can block users from admin area. once it's done, user will blocked in the platform and he can't connect with his account even he already pushed some commits. In this case, Jenkins shouldn't send emails any more for these blocked users

Comment: As I said, that's GitHub functionality, not git. The two are very different things.

Comment: How could it be only on Github since I can do it from my Gitlab admin area ? Please check My edit, I added a screenshot to the functionality in Gitlab !

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread. Then, it is your _GitLab_ functionality (GitLab being a clone of GitHub, they have similar functions.) _Not_ git.

Comment: Ah thank you :) for a second, I thought maybe there was something I had missed :D. I corrected the sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go [here](https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens) (or rather, the equivalent setting on your private GitLab: User Settings > Access Tokens) and generate an access token with `read_user` permission. Be sure to copy it, or you'll never see it again (and you'll have to make a new one).
- You can issue this command:

  ```
  curl -H "Private-Token: $token" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/?username=$username"
  ```

  where `$token` is the token you created, and `$username` the GitLab username of the user you want to check. (Again, you will probably need to adjust the URL to match where your GitLab is, I don't think you're talking about gitlab.com here.) You can also search by email, using `search=$email` instead of `username=$username`.

  You will get a JSON. One of the fields is `state`, which can be `active` or `blocked`. You can use the `jq` utility, or any higher programming language, to parse the JSON and find the value of the `state` field.

  Alternately, you can append `&active=true`; this way, you get the user if he's unblocked, or an empty array (`[]`) if blocked. This would be easier to test in bash, as you simply need to see if the result is `"[]"` or not. (You can also have the opposite test with `&blocked=true` to only return the user(s) if blocked.)

You can find the relevant documentation [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html).